# How can I calculate the hysteresis of Reed sensor?

Tags: sensor, proximity-sensor, hysteresis, reed-switch

As question says, I want to calculate the hysteresis of Reed sensor and I don't know how. As I seen in Reed sensor's documentation, hysteresis may be x/y, or the difference between x and y, and I'm not sure which is true.[image]

Comment: I see the picture and understand it but it's not clear what is confusing you.

Comment: How can I calculate hysteresis based on this picture?. I have a set of values for Reed sensor. For example if x = -20 and y = 15, how can I calculate hysteresis based on this? I mean, which is the formula for hysteresis calculation?

Comment: I have no idea what those numbers are or represent.

Comment: Those numbers represent distance of magnet from reed sensor, they are coordinates.

Comment: So, what is it that confuses you?

Comment: I got an answer to this question. Also thank you for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't *calculate* the hysteresis of a reed switch sensor, you *measure* it, or read it from the data sheet.

What the diagram is telling you is that you have to get close with the magnet to switch on, but then it stays on until you pull the magnet further away.

The hysteresis has to be defined in a way that is *useful* to you. You could define it as the ratio of the distances, or as the absolute difference between the distances. The use in the data sheet of the % symbol indicates that they are defining it as the distance ratio.

Note that the magnetic field at the switch is *not* proportional to the distance of the magnet, so the ratio of distances is *not* equal to the ratio of fields required at the reed. If you were driving the reed switch with a magnetic coil round the switch, then field ratio would be more useful to you, and you'd define it and measure it that way.

Comment: I understand it. `Absolute difference between the distances`is what I was looking for. Thank you for your explanation sir.